# Is Huygens' Law satisfied in the following case?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses, huygens-principle

I have a GRIN lens with the refractive index varying linearly with y, and supposedly this lens tilts the wavefront. [image]

Since the rays are travelling normally in both refractive index materials, they stay normal to the plane of the lens at all times. However the wavefront travelling with them tilts because of different speed of light for different indices, and gives a wavefront like this. Is this correct? Or do the rays themselves tilt? I don't think this is a possibility since the rays are always perpendicular to the plane.

If my reasoning is correct, does this satisfy Huygens' Law? It states that the wavefront must be perpendicular to the path of the waves at all times, but this doesn't seem to be the case here, which leads me to thinking its the waves themselves that are tilting.

Diagrams like this can be found on the internet, but I do not understand how are the waves tilting when they enter normally,
[image]

What am I missing? I found this situation while solving a problem in a book (Pathfinder for Olympiad Physics) but upon thinking a bit more was fell into this confusing situation.

Answer (score 4):

If by Huygens' principle, properly modified by the obliquity factor, you mean that each point of the wavefront is a source of spherical wavelets then it is *not* true for a variable index material.

If by Huygens' principle, properly modified by the obliquity factor, you mean that each point of the wavefront is a *local* point-source of wavelets then it *is* also true for a variable index material.

The reason for the difference is that a spherical wavefront in a homogeneous medium stays spherical while in a variable index medium the wavefront gets distorted as it propagates. But Huygens' principle taken as to mean that every point of a propagating wavefront is a source of a new wave still holds in this sense. Unfortunately, in an inhomogeneous medium the principle is then less useful because the type of elementary wavelets that are emitted from each point on a wavefront varies form wavefront to another wavefront and it also varies from one point to another point on the same wavefront.

Comment: Does this means that the wavelets emitted get distorted? In that case does it imply that perpendicularity of travelling waves to the wavefront is not a necessary criterion for Huygens to be followed?

Comment: The usual definition of the ray vector that it is parallel with the direction of the local propagation of the Poynting vector in an *isotropic* medium, and it is the *gradient* of the wavefront function, the latter being the constant phase surfaces.  The local gradient is, of course, perpendicular to the local surface tangent. This is true for an inhomogeneous medium as well. Huygens' principle is true still but the constant phase surfaces emitted from any point source are not spherical.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. The wavelets are no more spherical, so this implies that the diagram in question is right since it follows from Snell's laws and the wavelets distort in such a way that the wavefront is as such. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, that is right, but do not forget that even Snell's law must be understood in a *local* sense if the medium is continuously varying. You can only use the conventional form of Snell's law if the medium is piece-wise homogeneous as in a layered material.

Comment: for a layered material, because of the wavefront distortion, it is usually easier to calculate first the rays via Snell's law and then if still interested calculate the surface to which they are orthogonal, the wavefront itself. The Malus-Dupin theorem assures that those surfaces to which the rays are orthogonal always exist and unique. There are methods to calculate image distortion using rays and others using the wavefront itself. By distortion is meant how closely the rays meet at a point or how closely a wavefront is shrinking to a sphere, etc.

Comment: "the surface to which they are orthogonal, the wavefront itself", this implies that wavefronts are orthogonal, this seems to be a contradiction to your previous agreement with the diagram?

Comment: The rays are always defined in an isotropic medium to be the envelope of the vectors orthogonal to the local wavefront. For a point source emitting spherical waves the rays are radial, if the waves are not spherical then the rays are not radial where by radial is meant a straight line connecting the original source point with the one on the wavefront.

Comment: I am sorry for this extended discussion but can you tell me which of the diagrams you deem correct which are mentioned in the question? The first one or the second one?

Comment: I have just noticed that you have updated your question but I do not see the difference between them. As the wave goes longitudinally through a homogeneous direction in a transversally inhomogeneous, not layered but continuous, medium the wave will tilt and the wavefront will be a single continuous surface. If the medium is layered then the situation is more complicated by the wavefront breaking up into "segments", if those are a wavelength apart in the following homogeneous medium the they recombine into a new surface that is tilted, see the Fresnel lens.

Comment: My only confusion lies in _how are the waves tilting even though Snell's law predicts they should come out normally?_. The second diagram violates that the first one just shows waves coming out normally, the wavefront drawn in the first one isnt perpendicular to the waves emitted. The refractive index varies continuously throughout the medium.

Comment: read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array

Comment: I finally understand how is this working, basically the transmission speed of the wavelets is also decreased in the GRIN lens, so the wavefront tilts (just like in phased arrays the wavelets are emitted late to tilt the wavefront, same mechanism just execution is different here). This implies the conventional form of Snell's law doesn't hold. What is the unconventional form (you state that the conventional form cant be used)?

Comment: I meant to say that, in general, Fermat's principle, or its local equivalent, Snell's law, hold if the refractivity of the medium is continuous. If the medium is layered, for example, then certain otherwise normal lines cannot be rays; for example, any line on the interface between two homogeneous planar layers cannot be rays. The discontinuity also shows up in the Huygens' principle and in its equivalent Malus-Dupin theorem by having piece-wise continuous equal phase surfaces that are not joined because of the discontinuous refractive index across the interface.